# Express js - find is not a function

Tags: express, mern

I'm trying to create a simple MERN app

I have a server.js file with a schema and one get route

When I try to test the get route with postmaster I get an error

I'm sure Ive done this before with the same code and I'm only using one route and I'm still getting this error.

```
TypeError: Item.find is not a function
    at router.get (/Users/user/Documents/_Work/cd/MERN/vs-mern-list/routes/api/items.js:7:10)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/user/Documents/_Work/cd/MERN/vs-mern-list/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/user/Documents/_Work/cd/MERN/vs-mern-list/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/Users/user/Documents/_Work/cd/MERN/vs-mern-list/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/user/Documents/_Work/cd/MERN/vs-mern-list/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /Users/user/Documents/_Work/cd/MERN/vs-mern-list/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/Users/user/Documents/_Work/cd/MERN/vs-mern-list/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/user/Documents/_Work/cd/MERN/vs-mern-list/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at Function.handle (/Users/user/Documents/_Work/cd/MERN/vs-mern-list/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
    at router (/Users/user/Documents/_Work/cd/MERN/vs-mern-list/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/user/Documents/_Work/cd/MERN/vs-mern-list/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/user/Documents/_Work/cd/MERN/vs-mern-list/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /Users/user/Documents/_Work/cd/MERN/vs-mern-list/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/Users/user/Documents/_Work/cd/MERN/vs-mern-list/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/user/Documents/_Work/cd/MERN/vs-mern-list/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at /Users/user/Documents/_Work/cd/MERN/vs-mern-list/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:130:5
```

My files are:

server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const items = require('./routes/api/items');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

const db = require('./config/keys').mongoURI;

mongoose
  .connect(db ,{ useNewUrlParser: true })
  .then(() => console.log('db connected'))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));

app.use('/api/items', items);  

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log('server connected'));
```

Item.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const ItemSchema = new Schema({
  name:{
    type: 'String',
    required: true 
  },
  Date:{
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
})

module.export = Item = mongoose.model('item', ItemSchema);
```

items.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

const Item = require('../../models/Item');

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    Item.find()
        .then(items => res.json(items))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 3):

**Your module export is incorrect**.

In express, There should not be export like this

```
module.export = Item = mongoose.model('Item', ItemSchema);  
//or
mongoose.exports = mongoose.model('Item', listSchema);
```

it should be

```
module.exports = Item = mongoose.model('Item', ItemSchema); 
//or
module.exports = mongoose.model('Item', ItemSchema);
```